# Não consigo "ler" um JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rest

Estou trabalhando na ferramenta FLUIG (TOTVS), e quero ler um JSON que é entregue via REST. 
Aqui está uma foto da URL (intranet):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conteúdo:

```
{"content":{"Matrícula_RH":"10555","UserDocLanguage":"pt_BR","UserEmailHTML":"true","UserProjects":"","UserQuotaDocument":"500","UserSpecialization":"","UserWorkflowGroup":"TI","UX-APP-COMPANY":"88303375000171_0240050312_RS","WCMUserLang":"pt_BR"},"message":{"message":"OK","detail":"OK","type":"INFO","errorCode":null}}
```

Código leitura JSON:

```
function executa() {
    var url = "http://10.0.0.1:8181/api/public/2.0/users/listData/teste";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var contador = json.length;
            alert(contador);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

porem sempre dá este erro no console do navegador(chrome):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (rest.html:17)
```

Quando eu olho, a linha com erro é esta:

```
var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Estou tratando o JSON de forma errada? Peguei este código pela internet e achei ele bem genérico, pesquisei sobre este erro e testei algumas alterações sem sucesso. Sou bem iniciante no javascript, se alguém souber me explicar o porque isso não dá certo e qual o método correto eu agradeço.

Tentei um novo código que funcionou só preciso aprender a como pegar o conteúdo do JSON:

```
function executa_new() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://10.0.0.1:8181/api/public/2.0/users/listData/teste',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function() {    
            console.info("foi");
        }, error: function(e){
             alert('Ocorreu um erro durante a chamada ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Dá uma `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` para ver o  que tem na saída. com f12 -> console você consegue verificar o resultado. Outra coisa, tenta `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText.content)`

Comment: Ele traz uma página HTML completamente diferente: https://pastebin.com/LQkCFtKz

Comment: veja a o arquivo que você chama pelo ajax, o problema pode estar nele q está chamando alguma coisa que retorna informação antes da hora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
function executa_new() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://10.0.0.1:8181/api/public/2.0/users/listData/teste',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);
            console.info(data.content);
            console.info(data.content["Matrícula_RH"]);

        }, error: function(e){
             alert('Ocorreu um erro durante a chamada ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!